# Background in DataGrid Header

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles

I'm working on a style for my `DataGrid` and I have a little problem shown in the picture below.

[image]

If the header of the `DataGrid` doesn't fill the width There is some gradient background and a bottom and right border. Is there a way to get rid of these 2 things and make it look like in the following picture? *(Picture made with PhotoShop for illustration purposes)*

[image]

Below is the style for my `DataGrid`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                         Color="#F50099FF" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}"
                         Color="#FFCCFFFF" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}"
                         Color="#F50099FF" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}"
                         Color="#FFCCFFFF" />
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem"
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility"
            Value="None" />
    <Setter Property="RowHeaderWidth"
            Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="RowBackground"
            Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground"
            Value="#F5E5E5E5" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionMode"
            Value="Single" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionUnit"
            Value="FullRow" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer"
                                  Focusable="False">
                        <ScrollViewer.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.SelectAll"
                                            Focusable="False"
                                            Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                            Width="{Binding CellsPanelHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}">
                                        <Button.Visibility>
                                            <Binding Path="HeadersVisibility"
                                                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}">
                                                <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                                                    <DataGridHeadersVisibility>All</DataGridHeadersVisibility>
                                                </Binding.ConverterParameter>
                                            </Binding>
                                        </Button.Visibility>
                                    </Button>
                                    <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter"
                                                                    Grid.Column="1">
                                        <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter.Visibility>
                                            <Binding Path="HeadersVisibility"
                                                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}">
                                                <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                                                    <DataGridHeadersVisibility>Column</DataGridHeadersVisibility>
                                                </Binding.ConverterParameter>
                                            </Binding>
                                        </DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter.Visibility>
                                    </DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter>
                                    <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
                                                            CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}"
                                                            CanHorizontallyScroll="False"
                                                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                                            CanVerticallyScroll="False"
                                                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                            ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"
                                                            Grid.Row="1" />
                                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                                               Grid.Column="2"
                                               Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                                               Orientation="Vertical"
                                               Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                               Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                               Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                               ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" />
                                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                                               Grid.Row="2"
                                               Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                               Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                                               Orientation="Horizontal"
                                               Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                               Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                               ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ScrollViewer.Template>
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Next style is the `ColumnHeader`:

```
<Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderStyleRight"
       TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border BorderBrush="#DBDBDB"
                            Background="White"
                            BorderThickness="0.5 1 1 1"
                            Padding="3"
                            CornerRadius="0 5 5 0">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="14" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                            <Path x:Name="SortArrow"
                                  Grid.Column="1"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  Width="8"
                                  Height="6"
                                  Margin="3 0"
                                  Stretch="Fill"
                                  Fill="Black"
                                  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0.4"
                                  Visibility="Collapsed"
                                  Data="M0,0 L1,0 0.5,1 z" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <!--<Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}" />
                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                           Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}" />-->
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="SortDirection"
                             Value="Ascending">
                        <Setter TargetName="SortArrow"
                                Property="Visibility"
                                Value="Visible" />
                        <Setter TargetName="SortArrow"
                                Property="RenderTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="180" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="SortDirection"
                             Value="Descending">
                        <Setter TargetName="SortArrow"
                                Property="Visibility"
                                Value="Visible" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And in my actual `DataGrid` I have a column like this:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredOrders.View}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOrder}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Groep"
                            Binding="{Binding Workcenter.Section.Section}"
                            HeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyleRight}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: @Sheridan, I added the necessary code I think.

Comment: This code does not exhibit your problem because your custom `Header`s take up the full width of the column as expected. Also, there's no point in providing code full of references to your resources because we don't have them. You should remove them if you would like help from users here.

Comment: @Sheridan, I have removed the references in the code that I made myself. All other references are provided or were there when the template was created by Blend. As far as I know, if you don't set a `Width` to a column it will fit to it content. Let say my `DataGrid` is 500 px wide and my `Columns` combined are only  450 px wide. This will give a 50 px gap like my picture illustrates.

Comment: @Krowi - One workaround would be to make the last column fill all available empty space.

Comment: Nope... it still doesn't exhibit your problem. Maybe you should [*create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @RohitVats, then I still have the corners since the Header has rounded ones.

Comment: @Krowi - It will be there but area would be too small to notice. Anyhow, I suspect it's coming from default template of DataGrid. To get it fixed you have to tweak a bit default template (most probably coming from DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter default template).

Comment: @Krowi - If its fine to not have rounded corners for last column, you can have duplicate HeaderStyle without rounded corners and apply that on last column.